# Siri remote (ATV4) with raspberry pi 3 bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, apple-tv, siri-remote

I have a raspberry pi 3 and a 4th generation apple tv remote.

I don't understand why I am unable to see the remote when I scan with the raspberry pi using "hcitool scan" command.

I have to say that I can see other bluetooth device during the scan but never the remote.

I can see the remote when I scan with my iPhone.

My ATV4 is unplugged and i have put the remote on pair mode (menu + volume up)

What is wrong ? Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same result. The remote is visible in my iPhone, but can't see it at all from hcitool scan. Other bluetooth devices show up fine in hcitool scan.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I have been able to see the remote using sudo hcitool lescan then I have been able to connect doing sudo gatttool -b <adress> -I then connect but after that I have no idea how to catch buttons events.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this for a little while, and my conclusion so far is that there may be something a bit non-standard or unusual about the bluetooth in the Siri Remote / 4th generation Apple TV remote. Certainly it manages to upset LightBlue on my Mac and iPhone in slightly different ways.

If I use bluetoothctl, the remote does show up and I can connect to it (at least if I hold menu+volumeup for 5 seconds whilst bluetoothctl has discovery enabled):

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:6C:15:98 raspberrypi [default]
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:6C:15:98 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[NEW] Device 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14 DJ7Q6MZ9GQQT
[NEW] Device 67:8F:99:BC:EE:C5 67-8F-99-BC-EE-C5
[CHG] Device 67:8F:99:BC:EE:C5 RSSI: -64
[CHG] Device 67:8F:99:BC:EE:C5 RSSI: -44
[CHG] Device 67:8F:99:BC:EE:C5 RSSI: -64
[CHG] Device 67:8F:99:BC:EE:C5 RSSI: -44
[bluetooth]# connect 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14 
Attempting to connect to 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14
[CHG] Device 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14 UUIDs:
    00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    0000181e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    8341f2b4-c013-4f04-8197-c4cdb42e26dc
[CHG] Device 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14 Appearance: 0x03c0
[CHG] Device 78:9F:70:5E:A3:14 Modalias: bluetooth:v004Cp0266d0000
```